# C# saving object from NodeList xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have such xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Pepole>
  <PersonList>
    <Person>
      <Name>aa</Name>
      <Surname>asdf</Surname>
      <City>asdf</City>
    </Person>
  </PersonList>
  <PersonList>
    <Person>
      <Name>aa</Name>
      <Surname>dafsd</Surname>
      <City>dafdsa</City>
    </Person>
  </PersonList>
  <PersonList>
    <Person>
      <Name>asdf</Name>
      <Surname>asdfasdf</Surname>
      <City>asdfadsf</City>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>asdfsadf</Name>
      <Surname>Dasfdasdf</Surname>
      <City>asdfdsaf</City>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>asdfdsaf</Name>
      <Surname>asdfdsaf</Surname>
      <City>asdfdsaf</City>
    </Person>
  </PersonList>
</Pepole>
```

Method:

```
public static void SendTheLoadedPerson(ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Person>> list)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
    XmlNodeList nodes2 = root.SelectNodes("//Pepole/PersonList/Person");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var items = (from r in doc.Root.Elements("Person")

        select new Person()
        {
            Name = (string)r.Element("Name"),
            Surname = (string)r.Element("Surname"),
            City = (string)r.Element("City")
        }).ToList();

        list.Add(new ObservableCollection<Person>(items));
    }
}
```

And now I have a problem, because the XmlNode returns fine - 3 Personlist and inside the Person, but I would like to asigne [count of nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDDHk.jpg) separately to the ObservableCollection> list.
I meant : When PersonList contains 2 person, I would like to send to the list 2 person, as one count, it's hard to explain to me so it's should looks like that:
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvS6s.jpg)

I will be very grateful for any tips / help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the fourth time you posted the same question.  The newest posting has slightly different xml.  Below is the solution provided in one of these postings using latest xml and adding a count.  Your solution is more complicated using Elements instead of Descendants.  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("PersonList").Select(x => new {
                count = x.Elements("Person").Count(),
                people = x.Elements("Person").Select(y => new {
                    name = (string)y.Element("Name"),
                    surname = (string)y.Element("Surname"),
                    city = (string)y.Element("City")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```